# What's the difference between latch and lock?

Tags: differences, nouns

I know what a lock is. But what is a latch? It seems that it is similar to a lock. What's the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A latch fastens a door, gate or window in position but does not provide security. (See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latch_%28hardware%29).)

A lock prevents anyone without a key from opening a door/gate/etc.

Comment: Bonus points for an image of a latch.

Answer (score 7):

A *latch* keeps something closed but does not *lock* it.

Answer (score 5):

A latch is a very simple device that keeps a door or window closed. On a door, it is simply a sliding piece of metal or wood that slips into a slot, or even a piece of rope with a loop that can go over a small post.

A lock needs a separate device (a key) that will unlock the lock.